# Como evitar que uma nova instância da Activity seja criada a cada Intent

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

Na minha aplicação eu tenho um `BroadCast`que recebe `push notifications` em `background`, esse `push`atualmente abre uma activity com as informações de uma solicitação para ser aceita, o que acontece é que se no mesmo instante que estiver lendo uma solicitação receber outra o app abre por cima em uma nova Intent.

```
public class BroadcastReceiverOneSignal extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getBundleExtra("data");
    try {
        JSONObject customJSON = new JSONObject(extras.getString("custom"));
        if(customJSON.has("a")){

            String id = customJSON.getJSONObject("a").getString(Constants.ID_CORRIDA);

            Intent i = new Intent(context, Activty.class);
            i.putExtra(Constants.ID, id);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse conjunto de flags só faz o que pretende se o `launchMode` da Activity for `singleTop`.

No arquivo *AndroidManifest.xml*, na declaração dessa *Activity*, coloque:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

A *Activity* só será criada se ela não estiver em execução, caso esteja ela receberá o *intent* no método `onNewIntent()`.

O mesmo resultado pode ser obtido com:

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Em ambos os casos o novo Intent e o respectivo Extra pode ser obtido no método `onNewIntent()`.

Comment: Eu consigo manter todos os dados de outros pedidos, caso eu receba um novo?

Comment: Sim, o novo será recebido no método `onNewIntent()`